# Buffer(s) option missing

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing, buffer, tools, plugins

I want to create a buffer on a certain layer that will have radios of n meters.

I go to `vector->geoprocessing tools ->` and then nothing `buffer(s)` is missing I have enabled the Spatial Query Plugin

Any idea how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of where the tools would normally appear?

Comment: It's right there in your screenshot: Fixed distance bufffer

Answer (score 1):

The location of the >buffer tool should be located as displayed in the screen shot below:

[image]